# Async coding in C#, not able to get the second element to work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, desktop

The goal of this project in C# is to browse for a txt file in each box (that coding works) and hit submit and each side will run to select the top ten repeated words in each listbox. I have got most of the code to work but I can only get book 1 side to run and not book 2. Attached is the code as well as the image to help understand! Using Windows Desktop (.NET) application.

[image: Image on the form being used]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Asynchronous_Program
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close();
    private async void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            var file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            var wordTask = ReadBook(file);
            tasks.Add(wordTask);

      
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        //Other operations after this has finished

        }



    private async Task ReadBook(string filename)
    {
        var lines = await Task.FromResult(File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filename));
        var arrayLinesWithoutPunctuation =
            lines.Result.Where(x => x != String.Empty)
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(x => x.ToLower().Trim().Replace(",", "").Replace("{", ""));
        var arrayOfWords = arrayLinesWithoutPunctuation.SelectMany(x => x.Split(" "));
        Dictionary<string, int> wordDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        arrayOfWords.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            if (wordDic.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                wordDic[x] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                wordDic.Add(x, 1);
            }
        });

        var top10 = wordDic.Where(x => 
   !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Key)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(10);
        foreach(var word in top10)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(word.Key + " - " + word.Value);
            listBox2.Items.Add(word.Key + " - " + word.Value);
        }
    }

    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.Split("\\").LastOrDefault();
        }

    }

    private void btnBrowse2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFileName2.Text = openFileDialog2.FileName.Split("\\").LastOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] post to explain `var lines = await Task.FromResult(File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filename));` line of code? Clearly you wanted to achieve something with that... but it is quite unclear what exactly.

Comment: So what you want is when you click the "Submit" button, to start two concurrent `ReadBook` operations instead of just one?

Comment: `btnSubmit_Click` only creates one task, it needs to create two, one for each listbox.

Comment: I would suggest to replace all `var` occurrences in the code with the actual types of the variables. The `var` is a great convenience when writing code in Visual Studio, but when posting code on StackOverflow, we can only guess the types. We can't hover the mouse over the `var`, and get the information that we want!